# 'SiteOrigin Google Maps' widget conflicting with 'ProtheusThemes'

Tags: google-maps

not sure if this is the right forum, but I wanted to share the experience.

on wordpress site that I manage I'm having trouble displaying google map...

I'm using some ProtheusTheme that seem to cover also displaying google maps, but somehow I use also 'SiteOrigin Google Maps' widget and 'API Key for google maps' plugin

I know that this is perhaps not recommended combination, see ProtheusThemes forum [here](https://support.proteusthemes.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206392779-Google-Maps-API-error-message) or [here](https://support.proteusthemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/208650749-Google-Maps-not-working-),
 
but it worked fine so far, until my wordpress automatically updated 'SiteOrigin widget bundle' plugin to version 1.8.1

I have fixed it by turning back to 'SiteOrigin widget bundle' 1.7.2
and disabled automatic updates by putting: `define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );` in `wp-config.php` file. (I believe this is right setting),
but I understand that this is not the 'state of art' solution, any suggestions?